# Is there a way to mathematically prove $\psi (\mathbf{r})$ varies continuously (using the intuitive arguments provided below)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, continuity, potential-theory

Electric potential at a point outside the charge distribution is:

$\displaystyle \psi (\mathbf{r})= \int_{V'}
\dfrac{\rho (\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} dV'$

where:

$\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ is coordinates of field point

$\mathbf{r'}=(x',y',z')$ is coordinates of source point

$\rho (\mathbf{r'})$ is the density of charge distribution

PART:$(1)$ If we move from one point $\mathbf{r_1}$ to another point $\mathbf{r_2}$ (through a path outside the charge distribution), $|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|$ varies continuously. There is no variation in $\rho (\mathbf{r'})$ and limits of integration w.r.t $V'$. So intuitively **$\psi (\mathbf{r})$ varies continuously**. Using these arguments, is there a way to mathematically prove this?

PART:$(2)$ Is there a simple mathematical way to prove $\dfrac{\partial \psi (\mathbf{r})}{\partial x}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\psi(x+h,y,z)-\psi(x,y,z)}{h}$ exists?

Comment: The point is that if $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function of $x$, then $\int_B f(x,y)\,dy$ is continuous. In your case, the function will be continuous so long as $\mathbf r$ stays outside $V'$.

Comment: I will do this later. To make life easier, tell me what kind of region your $V’$ is.

Comment: No. Is it compact?

Comment: $V'$ is closed and bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to prove is this. If $f$ is a continuous function of $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3$, and $y$ varies over a compact (closed and bounded) domain $V'\subset\Bbb R^3$, then the function
$$F(x) = \int_{V'} f(x,y)\,dy$$
is continuous.

Fix a point $x_0$ and a closed ball $\bar B(x_0,R)$ of radius $R$. Then the set $\bar B(x_0,R)\times V'$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3$. A continuous function on such a compact set is *uniformly continuous*. This means that given any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ so that whenever $\|(x,y)-(x',y')\|<\delta$, we'll have $|f(x,y)-f(x',y')|<\epsilon$. This means, in particular, that whenever $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$, we'll have $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|<\epsilon$ for every $y\in V'$. Thus, whenever $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$, we have
\begin{align*}
|F(x)-F(x_0)| &= \left|\int_{V'} f(x,y)\,dy - \int_{V'} f(x_0,y)\,dy\right| \\ & = \left|\int_{V'} \big(f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)\big)dy\right| \\ &\le \int_{V'} |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|dy < \epsilon\,\text{vol}(V'),
\end{align*}
so $F$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Here's a sneaky way to show that you can differentiate under the integral sign (there are fancier ways, of course, with Lebesgue integration). For now, I'll assume $x$ is just a single variable, rather than a vector, but you can apply this to any component function. We assume $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous (which certainly holds in the case you're interested in). Let
$$\phi(t) = \int_{V'} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,y)\,dy \quad\text{and}\quad \Phi(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \phi(t)\,dt.$$
Note that, $\phi$ is continuous by our first result.
Then, interchanging the order of integration, we get
\begin{align*}
\Phi(x) &= \int_{V'}\int_{x_0}^x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,y)\,dt\,dy \\ &= \int_{V'} \big(f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)\big)\,dy = F(x)-F(x_0).
\end{align*}
It follows from the (first part of the) Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $F'(x) = \Phi'(x) = \phi(x) = \displaystyle{\int_{V'} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,dy}$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation in the answer. If you don't mind can you please answer the second part of the question using simple mathematics (just like you answered the first part)?

Comment: LOL ... Nothing like changing the question in the middle :P

Comment: I get your result, that is $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \displaystyle{\int_{V'} f(x,y)\,dy}=\displaystyle{\int_{V'} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,dy}$. But I need to show that LHS exists (i.e. LHS has only one value) so that this equation is meaningful.

Comment: @Joe, the proof shows that.

Comment: Please can you try to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375289/the-integral-is-not-iterated-integral-will-this-fact-prevent-us-from-swapping-t).