# The integral is not iterated integral. Will this fact prevent us from swapping the order of surface and volume integrals? Why? Why not?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral, potential-theory

Consider a continuous charge distribution in volume $V'$. Draw a closed surface $S$ inside the volume $V'$.

[image]

Consider the following multiple integral:

$$B= \iint_S       \Biggl(     \iiint_{V'}   \left[  \dfrac{\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})}{R^2}   \rho'\   \right] dV' \Biggl)  dS$$

where

$R=|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|$

$\mathbf{r'}=(x',y',z')$ is coordinates of source points

$\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ is coordinates of field points

$\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})$ is the angle between $R$ and normal to surface element

$\rho'$ is the charge density and is continuous throughout the volume $V'$

---

Since $\mathbf{r} \in S$, the function is not integrable in domain $V'$. So we use change of variables:

$$B= \iint_S        \Biggl(    \iiint_{V'}   \left[  \dfrac{\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})}{R^2}   \rho'\ {r'}^2 \sin \theta' \right] d\theta' d\phi' dr'  \Biggr) dS$$

$\bbox[yellow]{\text{Note that in this equation, $\theta'$ and $\phi'$ are w.r.t point $\mathbf{r} \in S $}}$

The inner volume integral is an iterated integral. While computing this iterated integral in spherical coordinates (here $\mathbf{r'}$ varies and $\mathbf{r}$ is constant), we take the origin of our spherical coordinate at point $\mathbf{r} \in S$. That is, $\mathbf{r}=(0,0,0)$

Therefore after computing this iterated integral, i.e. after applying the limits, we will not be getting a function of $(r,\theta,\phi)$ or $(x,y,z)$. Instead we will be getting a number. *This means we cannot carry out the surface integral by iterated integrals.* **Will this fact prevent us from swapping the order of surface and volume integrals? Why? Why not?**

---

If swapping the order of surface and volume integrals is valid:

\begin{align}
B &= \iiint_{V'}        \Biggl(    \iint_S   \left[  \dfrac{\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})}{R^2}   \rho'\ {r'}^2 \sin \theta' \right] dS   \Biggr) d\theta' d\phi' dr'\\
  &= \iiint_{V'}        \Biggl(    \iint_S   \left[  \dfrac{\cos(\hat{R},\hat{n})}{R^2}    \right] dS   \Biggr) \rho'\ {r'}^2 \sin \theta' d\theta' d\phi' dr'\\
\end{align}

$\bbox[yellow]{\text{Here in this last equation, $\theta'$ and $\phi'$ are w.r.t. which point?}}$

> **Special note for the answerer**
>
> This question may or may not be related to Fubini's theorem. If it is, please give the complete statement of Fubini's theorem and please show step-by-step how my question can be explained by Fubini's theorem. Please consider that I am a graduating student of Mathematics and I am learning real analysis (single and multivariable). Please try to explain within the scope of real analysis.

Comment: Is anyone here???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fubini's theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fubini_theorem) "establishes a connection between a [multiple integral](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Multiple_integral) and a [repeated [=iterated] one](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Repeated_integral)".

G. Kowalewski, [reviewing Fubini's 1907 paper](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A38.0343.02) (["Sugli integrali multipli," *Rom. Acc. L. Rend.* (5) 16, No. 1, 608](https://books.google.com/books?id=5SZ2qEfRon0C&pg=PA608)-614), defines the theorem:

> If $f(x,y)$ is integrable in a domain $\varGamma$ (in the sense of *Lebesgue*) and $d\sigma$ means the element of $\varGamma$, then one always has$$\int_{\varGamma}f(x,y)d\sigma=\int dy\int f(x,y)dx=\int dx\int f(x,y)dy.$$Over $\varGamma$ the condition is made that the intersection with $x$ = const. or $y$ = const. is linearly measurable (again in the sense of *Lebesgue*).
>
> At the end [of his paper], the author indicates how to transfer the given theorem to polar coordinates or other coordinates.

[Lebesgue integration](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lebesgue_integral) (which is based on measure theory) is an alternative approach to Riemann integration. See Lebesgue's dissertation

- H. Lebesgue, “[Intégrale, Longueur, Aire](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/ZY89GLGY/Lebesgue%20-%201902%20-%20Int%C3%A9grale,%20Longueur,%20Aire.pdf),” *Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata* (1898-1922) 7, no. 1 (December 1, 1902): 231–359,

which Fubini cites, or its translation in the section on Lebesgue in Hawking's [*God Created the Integers*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4339) pp. 1207-1253.